# problems with display after XML parsing

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, lxml

I am parsing an XML document that has a following structure:

```
<Distlist>
  <DistDoc>
     <Metadata></Metadata>
     <ArchiveDoc>
        <Article>
          <Para>aaaaaa</Para>
          <Para>bbbbbb</Para>
          <Para>cccccc</Para>
        </Article>
     </ArchiveDoc>
  </DistDoc>
</Distlist>
```

I have 5000 articles in each file and the full text of each article is broken into paragraphs. I am extracting the full text of the article with the following code (I use lxml):

```
doc = etree.parse(path) #Parse file
root=doc.getroot() #Get the root 

#Store full texts in list
full_texts = []
for child in root:
    full_texts.append("\n\n".join(child[1][0].itertext()))
```

When I see the output it's like this:

```
aaaaaaabbbbbbcccc
```

While my expected output (with double line break) was supposed to be:

```
aaaaaa

bbbbbb

cccccc
```

It's difficult to read when there is no separation between paragraphs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `article` nodes and join the texts of `para` nodes:

```
for article in root.xpath(".//Article"):
    texts = article.xpath(".//Para/text()")
    print("\n".join(texts))
```